# unexpected (no rows) result in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want a single code snippet that produces the id of a particular client and the number of client nodes linked, via the relationships below, to this client.  The following code produces the id of the client in my neo4j db:

```
MATCH (c1:Client {AtlasId:'F2A9452F-9B57-4F13-B314-0E4F63E04D0A'})
RETURN id(c1) as clientid
```

Great.  The following produces the number of clients nodes somehow linked to c1:

```
MATCH (c1:Client {AtlasId:'F2A9452F-9B57-4F13-B314-0E4F63E04D0A'})-
  [:`used email address`|:`was at`|:`used idnumber`|:`used`|:`used account`|:`used cellnumber`]-
  (m {AllowDuplication:false})-
  [:`used email address`|:`was at`|:`used idnumber`|:`used`|:`used account`|:`used cellnumber`]-
  (c2:Client {CountryRefId:1})
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT c2) as C2Count
RETURN C2Count
```

Also great.  Two pieces of code that does what I want.  Now I join the above like so:

```
MATCH (c1:Client {AtlasId:'F2A9452F-9B57-4F13-B314-0E4F63E04D0A'})
WITH id(c1) as clientid, c1
MATCH (c1)-
  [:`used email address`|:`was at`|:`used idnumber`|:`used`|:`used account`|:`used cellnumber`]-
  (m {AllowDuplication:false})-
  [:`used email address`|:`was at`|:`used idnumber`|:`used`|:`used account`|:`used cellnumber`]-
  (c2:Client {CountryRefId:1})
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT c2) as C2Count, clientid
RETURN clientid, C2Count
```

But the answer is (no rows).  The following at least produces C2Count = 0 (which is what I expected as there are none for this client):

```
MATCH (c1:Client {AtlasId:'F2A9452F-9B57-4F13-B314-0E4F63E04D0A'})
WITH id(c1) as clientid, c1
MATCH (c1)-
  [:`used email address`|:`was at`|:`used idnumber`|:`used`|:`used account`|:`used cellnumber`]-
  (m {AllowDuplication:false})-
  [:`used email address`|:`was at`|:`used idnumber`|:`used`|:`used account`|:`used cellnumber`]-
  (c2:Client    {CountryRefId:1})
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT c2) as C2Count
RETURN C2Count
```

Any ideas how I can consistently get the id number and the number of linked nodes even when there are NO linked nodes?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that when you perform a match and nothing matches, all rows that have been built up so far are wiped out. The match can't match on the pattern, so there's no results. You'd see the same thing if you performed both matches and then immediately returned `c1`: there would be no rows, because even though you previously matched to `c1`, it doesn't conform to the next match, it's not a valid result, so no rows are produced.

You can still perform aggregations even when there are no rows (performing `count()`, as you saw, results in 0; performing `collect()` should give you an empty collection). But you can't get property values from non-existent nodes. And any property values you projected that were previously present on result rows aren't there any more, as there are no rows in your results.

What you need is an OPTIONAL MATCH, where variables introduced in the OPTIONAL MATCH will be null if the match fails, but your rows will remain intact.

```
MATCH (c1:Client {AtlasId:'F2A9452F-9B57-4F13-B314-0E4F63E04D0A'})
WITH id(c1) as clientid, c1
OPTIONAL MATCH (c1)-
  [:`used email address`|:`was at`|:`used idnumber`|:`used`|:`used account`|:`used cellnumber`]-
  (m {AllowDuplication:false})-
  [:`used email address`|:`was at`|:`used idnumber`|:`used`|:`used account`|:`used cellnumber`]-
  (c2:Client {CountryRefId:1})
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT c2) as C2Count, clientid
RETURN clientid, C2Count
```